# regular expression replacement of numbers

Tags: regex, string, replace

Using regular expression how do I replace 1,186.55 with 1186.55?

My search string is

```
\b[1-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]
```

which works fine. I just can't seem to get the replacement part to work.

Comment: Just replace all `,` (commas) with nothing?

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression? Why not just delete the `,`?

Comment: It's a comma delimted file. Replacing all commas would ruin the field definition.

Comment: Regex itself is pattern matching, replacing the matched part is language dependent. How should we answer without knowing the language?

Comment: Standard regular expression in a text editor, no language involved. Seriously, if I knew how to program in java I wouldn’t be asking this question.

Comment: How should we know that? Which text editor? There is not really something like a "standard" regex. Additionally it would be extremely helpful if you would provide some input text to test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very sparse with information in your question. I try to answer as general as possible:

You can shorten the regex a bit by using quantifiers, I would make this in a first step

```
\b[1-9],[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2}
```

Most probably you can also replace `[0-9]` by `\d`, is also more readable IMO.

```
\b\d,\d{3}.\d{2}
```

Now we can go to the replacement part. Here you need to store the parts you want to keep. You can do that by putting that part into capturing groups, by placing brackets around, **this would be your search pattern:**

```
\b(\d),(\d{3}.\d{2})
```

So, now you can access the matched content of those capturing groups in the replacement string. The first opening bracket is the first group the second opening bracket is the second group, ...

Here there are now two possibilities, either you can get that content by `\1` or by `$1`

**Your replacement string would then be**

```
\1\2
```

**OR**

```
$1$2
```

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```py
def repl(initstr, unwanted=','):
    res = set(unwanted)
    return ''.join(r for r in initstr if r not in res)
```

Using regular expressions:

```py
from re import compile
regex = compile(r'([\d\.])')
print ''.join(regex.findall('1,186.55'))
```

Using [str.split()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) method:

```py
num = '1,186.55'
print ''.join(num.split(','))
```

Using [str.replace()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) method:

```py
num = '1,186.55'
print num.replace(',', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanna remove the comma you can do(in java or C#):

```
str.Replace(",", "");
```

(in java it's `replace`)

Answer (score 0):

Or in Perl:

```
s/(\d+),(\d+)/$1$2/
```